# How to Set Facebook Audience Network Native Ads after Every 6 Items Recycler view(GridView)

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I recently Started using Audience network. For Now I'm good at Audience Network Banners and Interstitials. But there is a problem with Native Ads. I want to Show native ads After Every 5 items. But Using this below code from Audience network GitHub sample native ad is displaying in the first item. but i want to show after every 5 items. So Can anyone please guide me to achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
return position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY == 0 ? AD_TYPE : POST_TYPE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the index value from 0 to 5 or 0 to 6. Try this code

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY == 5 ? AD_TYPE : POST_TYPE;

}
```

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work for you. I'll try some other methods.

Comment: It worked. I have another problem, the item in that place is covered by the ad. Can you help in this?